# How to delete a duplicate google scholar account?

Tags: google-scholar

I have moved to another University and created a new google scholar account here.  However, my old account at the former university still shows up and I get "you have a duplicate account" message.

Here's the rub:  I am no longer at my old university so I CAN'T LOGIN to that old account in order to delete it.   Google takes me to an authentication page for the old university for me to login.

So, I'm wondering how to delete that phantom account?

Thanks!  -Karl

Comment: Have you contacted Google?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP should contact Google.